# Can a TypeScript function be written to accept multiple types of Enums?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I read everything I could about how to use Generics in TypeScript to accept multiple types of Enums but nothing seemed to work.

```
enum Fruits {
  Apples,
  Oranges,
  Pears
}

enum Vegetables {
  Peas,
  Carrots,
  Lettuce
}

interface IDisplayOptions {
  options: any;
}

const DisplayOptions = ({ options }: IDisplayOptions) => {
  // Much code here
};
```

The `any` typing approach works but I thought this was a great use case for generics.  Could get it working though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could set `options: Fruits | Vegetables` but that isn't really very useful...

Comment: At runtime those enums are just numbers, so there's no way for the implementation of `DisplayOptions` to tell the difference between, say, `Fruits.Apples` and `Vegetables.Peas`.  Unless you want to pass in extra information, like... uh... [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOABRm)?  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz or I won't be notified)

Comment: It's really the typing I am trying to make generic.  Would you each be fine with just keeping `any`?  Or perhaps I could use `Array<number>`.  I'd rather not have to import the types of each type I want the function (which exists in a different file) to utilize.

Comment: You can use `any` or `number[]` or `Fruits | Vegetables`, but what can the body of `DisplayOptions` possibly do with the input? There's no type information about enums at runtime; the function receives something like `{options: 1}`. Is that `1` an orange or a carrot? Generally speaking the implementation and typing would need to know *which* kind of enum it's getting in order to be useful. What's the use case you're trying to support here? (And please, if you want me to be notified of a reply, mention @jcalz. Otherwise it's just chance whether I remember to check these comments)